# Problems using RunAs in TestComplete7

Tags: runas, testcomplete

I have a problem with running RunAs mode in TestComplete7.
I use:

```
var p = TestedApps.MyApp.RunAs("domain", "user", "password");
```

but without success.

I get this error:

```
**************************************************
Unable to run "MyApp" under the Domain\User account.

Make sure that the password and other parameters are valid and you have sufficient rights to run processes under another user account.
**************************************************
```

I'm running TestComplete in Administrator mode and I've done everything as explained in TestComplete Help.

Comment: Can you try using the runas command at the command prompt?  ex:
`runas /user:domain\username notepad`
Then do the same with your application. This will help eliminate some possible issues.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this TestComplete support article](http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/22947/) for troubleshooting tips. Some key points from this article:

- Is the *Secondary Logon* service running?
- Are the domain, user name and password valid and spelled correctly?
  Try Windows [`runas`](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) command with an arbitrary application (e.g. Notepad) and exactly the same credentials and see if it works.
- Is the password non-empty? (Accounts with empty passwords aren't supported for RunAs in TestComplete.)
- Does this account have [permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787794%28WS.10%29.aspx) for actually executing the application?

Comment: Secondary Logon is running. Password is not empty. I have permissions to execute application. I can run app, but it's not run under user I choose. If I use same command in Windows XP it works, but under Windows 7 it doesn't.

Comment: What about the Windows runas command? Have you checked if this works, as was suggested by Helen? Can you run your tested application using this command from the Command Prompt window?